# Comparing only the first index of two array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays one that has just one index which list id's. The other array has many indexes but I want to compare only the id index of both arrays which is index [0] I want to get only the rows that ids don't match and return those rows. Example:

```
$array1 = [
    '12345',
    '23457'
];

$array2 = [
   [id => '12345', 'fake_data' => 'something'],
   [id => '23457', 'more_data' => 'something else'],
   [id => '76389','more_data' => 'something else 3'],
   [id => '10293', 'more_data' => 'something else 4'],
   [id => '09229', 'more_data' => 'something else 5']
];
```

The first array just have id's the other has ids place other data. I need to keep that data and only return the rows that don't match the first array. Help is very much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$array1 = [
    '12345',
    '23457'
];

$array2 = [
   ['id' => '12345', 'fake_data' => 'something'],
   ['id' => '23457', 'more_data' => 'something else'],
   ['id' => '76389','more_data' => 'something else 3'],
   ['id' => '10293', 'more_data' => 'something else 4'],
   ['id' => '09229', 'more_data' => 'something else 5']
];

foreach($array2 as $key => $array)
    if(array_search($array['id'], $array1) !== false)
        unset($array2[$key]);

var_export($array2);
```

Output:

```
array (
    2 => 
    array (
      'id' => '76389',
      'more_data' => 'something else 3',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'id' => '10293',
      'more_data' => 'something else 4',
    ),
    4 => 
    array (
      'id' => '09229',
      'more_data' => 'something else 5',
    ),
  )
```

Comment: As in Jarad's answer you could swap the conditional for:  `if(in_array($array['id'], $array1))`. If you don't want to mutate the second array, copy it first.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array1 = [
    '12345',
    '23457'
];

$array2 = [
   ['id' => '12345', 'fake_data' => 'something'],
   ['id' => '23457', 'more_data' => 'something else'],
   ['id' => '76389','more_data' => 'something else 3'],
   ['id' => '10293', 'more_data' => 'something else 4'],
   ['id' => '09229', 'more_data' => 'something else 5']
];

$found_id_rows = array_filter($array2, function($row) use($array1) {
    return in_array($row['id'], $array1);
});

$not_found_id_rows = array_filter($array2, function($row) use($array1) {
    return !in_array($row['id'], $array1);
});
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12345
            [fake_data] => something
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23457
            [more_data] => something else
        )

)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 76389
            [more_data] => something else 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10293
            [more_data] => something else 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 09229
            [more_data] => something else 5
        )

)
```

**https://3v4l.org/6OVjP**

Comment: I wish I could up vote you both, but I can't so I'll have to up vote the first answer. I didn't use either both all three ways work so. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I think it looks like an `array_intersect` with two different types of arrays. To handle the different array types, you can use [`array_uintersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php), which takes a callback to define the comparison between items.

```
$result = array_uintersect($array2, $array1, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['id'] ?? $a) <=> ($b['id'] ?? $b);
});
```

The two terms `($a['id'] ?? $a)` and `($b['id'] ?? $b)` in the callback are like that because they can be terms from either `$array1` or `$array2`.

I don't know if this is any better or worse than the other solutions; it's just a different way of looking at it.